# HttpContext null in base class after converting from Framework WebForms to Core WebForms

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hi I am currently migrating asp.net web forms to asp.net core webforms where we have a basepage class that inherited by all pages where it handles the page session e.g

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs args)
    {
       BindData();
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        if(Session["UserName"].ToString()==null)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = "usera";
        }
    }
}


public partial class Index: BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

Now in .net core I am trying to do the same

```
  public class BasePage : PageModel
     {
         private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
         private DAL _dal = new DAL();
    
      
         public BasePage(IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             _configuration = configuration;
            BindData();
         }
    
         public void BindData()
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Session_DisplayName")))
             {
                       HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Session_DisplayName", "usera");
             }
         }
 }

 public class IndexModel : BasePage
 {
          public IndexModel(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
          {

          }

          public void OnGet()
         {
 
          }
 }
```

and getting below error

> HttpContext is null.
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you making the minimum effort to ensure the code is well-formatted instead of indented way to the right.

Comment: .NET Core doesn't have or support Webforms ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpContext is not available in the constructor of the Razor pages .For your requirement,you could try with HttpcontextAccessor as below:

```
public class BasePage : PageModel
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;




    public BasePage(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        BindData();
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("_Session_DisplayName")))
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Session_DisplayName", "User1");
        }
    }
}


public class IndexModel : BasePage
{
    public IndexModel(IConfiguration configuration,IHttpContextAccessor httpcontextaccessor) : base(configuration,httpcontextaccessor)
    {

    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Also,don't forget the required services and middleware in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession();
.......


app.UseSession();
```

Comment: updated BasePage Model,hopes help

Comment: i am getting httpconext is  null

Comment: Are these line in the correct order?_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        BindData();